# SPARK Join strategy in Cloud Datafusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

In cloud `Datafusion` I am using a joiner transform to join two tables.

One of them is a large table with about 87M Joins, while the other is a smaller table with only ~250 records. I am using 200 partitions in the joiner.

This causes the following failure:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 50 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   50.3 in stage 7.0 (TID xxx, cluster_workerx.c.project.internal, executor 6): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 6 exited caused by one of
>   the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 133355
>   ms java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.SparkException:
>   Application application_xxxxx finished with failed status

On a closer look into the spark UI the 200 tasks for the Join, nearly 80% of the 87m records go into one task O/P which fails with the heartbeat error, while the succeeded tasks has very few record O/P ~<10k records

Seems like spark performs a shuffle hash Join, is there a way in datafusion/cdap where we can force a broadcast join since one of my table is very small? Or can i make come configuration changes to the cluster config to make this join work?

What are the performance tuning i can make in the data fusion pipeline. I didnt find any reference to the configuration, tuning in the Datafusion documentation

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast(Dataset[T])` to mark a dataframe/dataset to be broadcasted while being joined. Broadcast is not always guaranteed but for 250 record it will work. If the dataframe with 87M rows is evenly partitioned then it should improve the performance.

Comment: Thanks Salim, but this will work when i am writing a spark code, however i am currently forced to use datafusion tool for my ETL which implements spark code in the background. For the Job submitted by datafusion i see that broadcast has not been implemented, i wanted to know if there is a way to make datafusion force a broadcast join, maybe some property that i need to set.

Comment: Spark does broadcast hash join by default when one dataset is small. There is a parameter to set the size limit for broadcast which you can try to play with

Comment: I have tried to set the autoBroadcastJoinThreshold value, unfortunately the join implemented is still not broadcast. From the spark UI i see that my larger table is repartitioned based on the key columns which causes an OOM error. Question is more related with CDAP tool,code the tool implements in case of joins and not with  spark. Have removed the tag of spark now to avoid confusion